# mass spectrum matching with cyclic peptide and linear peptide

Tags: proteins

I was doing a simple quiz which I encountered the following two questions related to mass spectrum matching with cyclic peptide and linear peptide.

I have done some preliminary google search, but I am not sure how to use either  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193859/find-a-cyclic-peptide-with-a-given-non-ideal-spectrum or https://github.com/rochoa85/pepfun in this case.

> Which of the following cyclic peptides could have generated the
> theoretical spectrum 0 71 101 113 131 184 202 214 232 285 303 315 345
> 416? (Select all that apply.)

```
TAIM

TMIA

MAIT

MTAI

TMLA

TLAM
```

> Which of the following linear peptides is consistent with Spectrum =
> {0 71 99 101 103 128 129 199 200 204 227 230 231 298 303 328 330 332
> 333}? (Select all that apply.)

```
AVQ

TCQ

TVQ

QCV

TCE

ETC
```

Answer (score 3):

You are way overthinking this.

As this is homework I won't give any code, but I will throw back some questions:

- What is the definition of m/z?
- Were the only tool available Wikipedia, could you simply read the infobox of each residue?
- If so, what values would you need and what elements do you need to subtract?
- Does residue order matter for linear and backbone cyclised peptides? (Let's ignore isoaspartate etc.)
- Have you been introduced to RDKit in your course? E.g. what would this give you?

```py
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
mol: Chem.Mol = Chem.MolFromFASTA('ELVIS')
print( Descriptors.ExactMolWt(mol) )
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I am stucked with many other things last week.  I am new to `rdkit`, but  `print( Descriptors.ExactMolWt(mol) )` would give `559.32172802` , and what can I learn from this number ?

Comment: and what do you exactly mean by **infobox of each residue** ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-to-charge_ratio and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Infobox

Comment: May I ask why you specifically chose `ELVIS` ?  or was it just a demo example ?

Comment: and I am not sure about **Does residue order matter for linear and backbone cyclised peptides? (Let's ignore isoaspartate etc.)**

Comment: Demo. The amino acid sequence `ELVIS` is an ancient joke as it is very common, but `ELVISISALIVE` was not present in the draft human genome.

Comment: but there is difference between linear peptide and cyclic peptide (which is more difficult to solve) ?

Comment: Wait, may I ask why would I need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass-to-charge_ratio for this question ?